# Hardness of Subgraph isomorphism problem for sparse pattern graph

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-algorithms, lower-bounds, parameterized-complexity, fine-grained

Subgraph isomorphism problem is a well studied problem: given graphs $G$ and $H$, one needs to answer if $H$ contains $G$ as a subgraph. It was proven that this problem requires $|H|^{\theta(|G|)}$ time assuming **ETH**. The easiest way to see this is to consider $G$ to be a clique and recall that $k$-clique problem requires $n^{\theta(k)}$ under **ETH** [1].

On the positive side, if $G$ is a path, a tree or a collection of small identical graphs we know how to solve Subgraph isomorphism in $f(|G|) |H|^{O(1)}$ time [2,3]. All these graphs are sparse, however I'm unaware of a general algorithm that runs in time $f(|G|) |H|^{O(1)}$, for all sparse graphs $G$.

My question is: do we know any conditional lower bounds for Subgraph isomorphism for sparse pattern graphs?

[1]*Chen, Jianer, et al. "Tight lower bounds for certain parameterized NP-hard problems." Information and Computation 201.2 (2005): 216-231.*

[2]*Koutis, Ioannis, and Ryan Williams. "Limits and applications of group algebras for parameterized problems." International Colloquium on Automata, Languages, and Programming. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2009.*

[3]*Fellows, Mike, et al. "Finding k disjoint triangles in an arbitrary graph." International Workshop on Graph-Theoretic Concepts in Computer Science. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2004.*

Comment: It is W-hard even when $G$ has maximum degree $3$, but FPT if $G$ has constant treewidth (all the above examples have constant treewidth). See https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.2187

Comment: That looks extremely helpful, thank you! I'm embarrassed I've missed the paper.

Comment: Maybe you just happen to know this: is any particular lower bound for bounded degree graphs (under ETH) follows from this paper?

Comment: It follows from an earlier paper of Marx ("Can you beat treewidth") that a $f(k)n^{o(k/\log k)}$ time algorithm would violate the ETH. Here n is the number of vertices in H and k is the number of vertices in G. This holds even when G has max degree 3 (but the degree of H is unbounded)

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. If you don't mind, maybe you can write this comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is $W[1]$-hard even when $G$ has maximum degree $3$, but $FPT$ if $G$ has constant treewidth (all the above examples have constant treewidth). See the paper [Everything you always wanted to know about the parameterized complexity of Subgraph Isomorphism (but were afraid to ask)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.2187) by Marx and Pilipczuk.

Indeed, it follows from an earlier paper of Marx: [Can You Beat Treewidth? Theory of Computing 6(1): 85-112 (2010)](http://www.theoryofcomputing.org/articles/v006a005/) that a $f(k)n^{o(k/\log k)}$
time algorithm would violate the ETH. Here $n$ is the number of vertices in $H$ and $k$ is the number of vertices in $G$. This holds even when $G$ has max degree $3$ (but the degree of $H$ is unbounded).